# how do I combine a macro parameter to an export statement in ssas

Tags: sas

I am trying to combine a macro parameter in to a PROC EXPORT statement for the OUTFILE path.
When I am writing in the path Q4 (Q for Quarter) everything is good.
When I try to replace Q4 with a macro %Quarter. SAS throws an error because of length over 260...

Comment: Please include the code you ran in the question, and any errors from the log as they appeared, in order to get the best possible answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters to a macro are stored in local macro variables.  So you would reference the parameter value in the code of your macro definition using &, not %.

```
%macro export(quarter);
   proc export data=data_for_&quarter file="/somepath/data_for_&quarter..csv"
       dbms=csv replace;
   run;
%mend export;
%export(Q4);
```

Just because SAS warns that the string is longer than 260 it does not necessarily mean you have an error.  But if you did not expect your path to be that long then you probably have unbalanced quotes.  It can be tricky to get that straightened out. Sometimes the easiest way to fix that is to start SAS over again.

Provide more details to get a more direct answer.